# SQL Query with Group by clause, with sum aggreagte

Tags: sql

i m having problem with this sql query, the query is self explanatory, so looking at it will tell u what problem i m having

```
SELECT customer.customerid, 
       paymentdata.paidamount, 
       paymentdata.balanceamount, 
       sum(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS Expr1 
FROM   customer 
       INNER JOIN paymentdata 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentdata.customerid 
       INNER JOIN paymentreceipt 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentreceipt.customerid 
GROUP  BY customer.customerid
```

Comment: I'm looking at it and the problem I see is that you haven't given me a clue what the problem is

Comment: where is the sum() aggregate? There should besomething like(sum(somecloumn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how do you want to calculate the other columns, you are grouping only by `customerid` but you want to show also `paymentdata.paidamount`,`paymentdata.balanceamount` and `paymentreceipt.paidamount`?

Consider that the group returns multiple rows for each group, so sql-server(or any other rdbms except MySql) doesn't know which row you want to show for the ungrouped columns. If you don't want to pick out a single row you have to aggregate the column. So e.g. by using `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX` or `AVG`:

For example:

```
SELECT customer.customerid, 
       MAX(paymentdata.paidamount) AS MaxPaid, 
       AVG(paymentdata.balanceamount) AS AverageBalance, 
       SUM(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS ReceiptPaidSum
FROM   customer 
       INNER JOIN paymentdata 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentdata.customerid 
       INNER JOIN paymentreceipt 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentreceipt.customerid 
GROUP  BY customer.customerid
```

Comment: i want to use this "sum(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS Expr1" only

Comment: @MirzaAsghirBaig: Edited my answer to use `SUM(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS ReceiptPaidSum`. But what do you want to do with the other two non-grouped columns?

Comment: i want to have something like this

Comment: @MirzaAsghirBaig: Your sentence is broken.

Comment: [link](http://picturepush.com/public/13196223) u can see what i want in this pic.

Comment: @MirzaAsghirBaig: So have you used `SUM` and it didn't work? If so, what error or wrong result did you get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30976/discussion-between-mirza-asghir-baig-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a few terms in your group by. All columns, other than aggregated ones, need to be included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an aggregate function for the columns not used in the group by clause

```
SELECT customer.customerid, 
       sum(paymentdata.paidamount), 
       sum(paymentdata.balanceamount), 
       sum(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS Expr1 
FROM   customer 
       INNER JOIN paymentdata 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentdata.customerid 
       INNER JOIN paymentreceipt 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentreceipt.customerid 
GROUP  BY customer.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer.customerid,paymentdata.customerid,paymentreceipt.customerid  
       paymentdata.paidamount, 
       paymentdata.balanceamount, 
       paymentreceipt.paidamount AS Expr1 
FROM   customer,paymentdata,paymentreceipt
       INNER JOIN paymentdata 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentdata.customerid 
       INNER JOIN paymentreceipt 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentreceipt.customerid 
GROUP  BY customer.customerid,paymentdata.customerid,paymentreceipt.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing aggregation, then you probably want aggregation functions:

```
SELECT customer.customerid, 
       sum(paymentdata.paidamount), 
       sum(paymentdata.balanceamount), 
       sum(paymentreceipt.paidamount) AS Expr1 
FROM   customer 
       INNER JOIN paymentdata 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentdata.customerid 
       INNER JOIN paymentreceipt 
               ON customer.customerid = paymentreceipt.customerid 
GROUP  BY customer.customerid
```

This probably still won't give you the right numbers, because you are getting a cross join on the payments and receipts.  If you want a better answer, then you should provide sample data and expected results in the question.